# How do I get the epoch time of a provided date natively on OS X?

Tags: macos, date, command-line, osx-yosemite

I've read [the manual](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/date.1.html); tried different formats, and I still cannot get the epoch time from a date:

```
$ date -j -f "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" "2014-11-20 16:38:06" "+%s"
Failed conversion of ``2014-11-20 16:38:06'' using format ``+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S''
date: illegal time format
usage: date [-jnu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... 
        [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]
```

The equivalent on Linux is `date -d "$DATE" "+%s"`. I need to compare two dates, and my next line of code is a simple `DIFF=((U - D))`. How do I get this from OS X's crazy `date` command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try:

```
date -j -f "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" "2014-11-20 16:38:06" "+%s"
```

Comment: Wait wait wait wait wait. ... What's different?

Comment: OH, IT'S THE DAMN PLUS SIGN!

Comment: Yea, annoying little details. Gets me every time, too!! Then I waste a lot of time on things which are correct.. :)